# Can I increase the number of processes in ArcGis Server 10.1?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, cache, parallel-processing

I use ArcMap 10.1. I have a map with many Mosaic and Raster layers. They are stored in many gdb-s. I publish this map with option "Create tiles on demand".

But this tiles are created very slowly (may be 2 minutes!!!). How increase the number of processes in arcgis server, which created this cache?

P.S. I know that ArcMap use only one сore. But maybe ArcGis server can use more cores?

***Update***

Thanks. I have the same problem. I set 24 cores. But CPU usages between 10-14%

Comment: There seems to be a similar thread on the [**ArcGIS Discussion Forums**](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/71321-Does-ArcGis-Server-10.1-take-advantage-of-multiple-cores).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several overlapping issues here.  ArcGIS Desktop is single-threaded, but can make use of a multi-core machine because it can then get the exclusive use of one core.  Unless there's a Direct Connect connection to an enterprise geodatabase, in which case, each connection will be run as an additional thread.

ArcGIS Server supports multiple cores innately due the "server and service" architecture (it also supports multi-threaded access to Direct Connect geodatabases).
The number of threads dedicated to any one service is controlled by the service properties (maximum and minimum number of instances):

[image: AGS Service Pooling]

I'll generally increase the maximum number of instances before building a cache, especially when it appears that it will take several days to build out all fourteen pyramid levels.

The "Create tiles on demand" option will actually reduce core the utilization, since it tells AGS to wait until maps are requested before populating the cache.

In order to be in compliance with licensing, you should have licensed additional bundles for your 24-core server.

Finally, it's possible that you are limited due to concurrent access to a slow I/O resource.  This is probably something to discuss with Tech Support.

Comment: I do not install ArcGis Server 10.1. We are used it about a year. How can I know our license?

Comment: I certainly can't tell you who in your organization would take care of tracking purchasing details.  Esri Customer Service and your marketing rep should be able to tell you what's been purchased, but not how they've been installed.